# When i am tried to solve the error then it give me an error like "soup" is not defined and "url" is not defined. Kinldy check

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```py
def get_all_images(url):
    """
    Returns all image URLs on a single `url`
    """
    soup = bs(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-c7ee359190ea> in <module>
      1 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
      2 urls = []
----> 3 for img in tqdm(soup.find_all("img"), "Extracting images"):
      4     img_url = img.attrs.get("src")
      5     if not img_url:

NameError: name 'soup' is not defined


NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-ea758e5abb54> in <module>
      1 # make the URL absolute by joining domain with the URL that is just extracted
----> 2 img_url = urljoin(url, img_url)

NameError: name 'url' is not defined
```

Comment: could you write the code between  ``` code here ```

Comment: add the function call!!!!!!! ...and a return soup to the function

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a minimum executable example... at least to copy past it.

`tqdm`not defined/given, conditional body missing

As mentioned in the comment, your function return `None`. Modified loop iterator: `get_all_images(url).find_all("img")`

```
def get_all_images(url):
    """
    Returns all image URLs on a single `url`
    """
    return bs(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = ''

for img in tqdm(get_all_images(url).find_all("img"), "Extracting images"):
    img_url = img.attrs.get("src")
        if not img_url:
           pass
```

Comment: I used  all the libraries which is required in this exercise. like tqdm, BeautifulSoup etc. I already solve this issue here is an some indentation error that's why compiler didn't fetch the right error and it gives the error that "URL", soup is not defined. Thanks for the answer and prompt consideration of my request.